# Java RegEx - Matching a list of arguments

Tags: java, regex, function, parameters

I am writing a custom parser using regular expressions, but I can't work out how to match functions.

An example of a function in my custom language is:

```
function int add(int num1, int num2){
  return num1 + num2;
}
```

My tokenizer uses RegEx to get the next token and remove it from the source code string supplied earlier. This means that when it comes to parsing a function, I can be sure that the code will start with the function statement.
I currently have the following expression:

```
^([\s]*function[\s]+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[\s]+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[\s]*\(([\s]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[\s]+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[\s]*)*\)[\s]*\{.*\}.*)$
```

It is very long, but it successfully matches these two functions:

```
function void log(string msg){
  Console.log(msg);
}
```

and

```
function int add(int num1 int num2){
  return num1 + num2;
}
```

I want to be able to split the arguments by a comma.

- I could make the comma required after a parameter, but then the last
  parameter would end with a comma.
- I could make the comma optional after a parameter, but then the user would be able to not put a comma in.

I need to be able to only require the comma between parameters, otherwise it will mess up my parser later.
How can I edit my expression to look for a comma between arguments?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly In which function do you want to add comma.

Comment: Forget it.  You can use a regex to pull individual tokens out of the string, but I wouldn't even try to parse entire constructs using a regex.  For one thing, there's no way to use a regex to parse a variable number of parameters and extract all the information.

Comment: I just want to match `(int num1, int num2)`. This is just `\(([\s]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[\s]+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[\s]*)*\)`. I need to check that the parameters are split by a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work for the `(int num1, int num2)` part of the string:

```
(\((?:\s*[^\s,]+\s+[^\s,]+\s*,)*\s*[^\s,]+\s+[^\s,]+\s*\))
```

It's easier to read when you space it out:

```
(\(
 (?:      \s*
   [^\s,]+\s+
   [^\s,]+\s*,
 )*       \s*
   [^\s,]+\s+
   [^\s,]+\s*
\))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could think of it as having 3 different possibilities: zero parameters, one parameter, and more than one parameter. Then just check using the or operator for each different possibility.

One Parameter:

```
(?:\\w+\\s+\\w+)
```

More than one parameter:

```
(?:\\w+\\s+\\w+)(?:\\,\\s+(?:\\w+\\s+\\w+))+
```

Zero Parameters:

```
\\s*
```

When using the or statement (all of the above):

```
((?:\\w+\\s+\\w+)|(?:\\w+\\s+\\w+)(?:\\,\\s+(?:\\w+\\s+\\w+))+|\\s*)
```